# File not found exception that does not make sense (For me)

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I have a program that reads and writes from a file. **I EVEN tried to create the file in `main`** but it still doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, 
                                              IOException, 
                                              FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Work in progress");

    File f = new File("Data.txt");
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            // Yes, it's there.


    UI ui = new UI();
    GenericDictionary<Integer> gd = new GenericDictionary<Integer>();
    Repository repo = new Repository("Data.txt", gd);
            // Should work, right ?
```

Now my Repository:

```
public Repository (String fileName, GenericDictionary gd) 
                                               throws IOException, 
                                                      NumberFormatException, 
                                                      FileNotFoundException {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.gd = gd;


    FileReader input = null;
    BufferedReader  inputBuffer = null;

    try {
        input = new FileReader(this.fileName);
        inputBuffer = new BufferedReader (input);

        String line;
        while ((line = inputBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] inputData = line.split(",");

            Node<Integer> newNode = new Node<Integer> (
                                       Integer.parseInt(inputData[0]),
                                       Integer.parseInt(inputData[1]));
            this.gd.add(newNode);
        }



    }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println(
               "Repository could not load data due to NumberFormatException: "
               + nfe); 
    }catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found, error: " + fnfe);
    }finally {
        inputBuffer.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Now even though I create my file it does not want to use it. Initially it was in the constructor of my repository, I moved it into the main file, still no success.

**This is what Eclipse prints within console:**

- Work in progress
  D:\Info\Java workspace\Laborator_4\Data.txt
  File not found, error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Data.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at repository.Repository.(Repository.java:49)
  at main.app.main(app.java:23)

Comment: you do not create a file in your code. `new File()` doesn't create a real file on your disk. did you take that into account?

Comment: Try using an absolute path name to avoid potentially looking in the wrong place. Also, you can call file.createNewFile() to effectively create a blank entry which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
File f = new File("Data.txt");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        // Yes, it's there.
```

That doesn't *create* a file on disk. It just creates a `File` object representing a path name. If you use:

```
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

*that* will show you whether or not it really exists.

So unless `D:\Info\Java workspace\Laborator_4\Data.txt` really, really exists, it's entirely reasonable for you to get an exception. Create the file and try again.

Additionally, you're getting a `NullPointerException` in your `finally` block because you're *assuming* that `inputBuffer` and `input` are both non-null: don't make that assumption. Check before closing.

Comment: Oh, now I feel silly. I just checked manually, it was indeed not there, but I did use the absolute path to see where **it should be**. Added it manually and now it works, ty. BTW how do you create a file then ?

Comment: How would it be best to check if they are not null ? Simply put an if within `finally` ? if they are null / are not null how should I react (if it's not the same thing for me at that point) ?

Comment: @Kalec: Yes, just check with `if (input != null) { input.close(); }` and likewise for `inputBuffer`. If the value is null, there's nothing to close...

Answer (score 2):

A File is an abstract path. Executing this:

```
File f = new File("Data.txt");
```

Does absolutley nothing on disk. Nor is this

```
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Any test for existence of the file.

Do this:

```
if(file.exists()) {
    // yes it's there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others Stated you don't create a file, try `touch()` method from here: [ApacheFileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#touch%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: I don't think there's need for that here. `File.createNewFile()` does the same.

Comment: Well, you are right. I just allways use the ApacheFileUtils if I do anything with Files, because it works out way better and has a lot of nice features. But include the jar to only use `touch()` will be an overkill for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works :

Replace this line

```
Repository repo = new Repository("Data.txt", gd);
```

with :

```
Repository repo = new Repository(f, gd);
```

and in your

```
public Repository (String fileName, GenericDictionary gd) 
                                           throws IOException, 
                                                  NumberFormatException, 
                                                  FileNotFoundException
```

use this

```
public Repository (File f, GenericDictionary gd) 
                                           throws IOException, 
                                                  NumberFormatException, 
                                                  FileNotFoundException
```

and in try { }
instead of

```
input = new FileReader(this.fileName);
```

do this

```
input = new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath());
```